# Laravel pagination links not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code on the view that is displaying for pagination correctly

```
{{$products->links()}}
```

The link created are correct:

```
http://demo.com/default?page=2
```

However, the items that is listed remains to be on the first page only. Could there be anything wrong?

FYI, in the controller I have this to generate the data

```
$products = \App\Product::paginate(1);
```

Comment: How did you construct `$products`

Comment: $products = \App\Product::paginate(1);